# SQL Sequence issue with order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql

```
SELECT @seq := IF(@win<=>win,@seq,0)+1 seq, 
@win := win win 
FROM fighterfighthistories, events 
where fighterid = 252 AND win IS NOT NULL AND 
fighterfighthistories.eventid=events.id 
ORDER BY events.eventon DESC, fighterfighthistories.id ASC
```

But I get the following results (seq seems to not follow the order by):

```
        seq win eventon
    1   1   1   31-12-2000
    2   9   1   30-12-2000
    3   1   1   21-12-2000
    4   2   1   11-12-2000
    5   1   0   10-12-2000
    6   1   0   01-12-2000
...
```

But I want it to return the following sequence (seq)

```
  seq   win
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   1
4   4   1
5   1   0
6   2   0
```

As you can see the sequence should start back once it gets to win=0.  It works if I don't use the order by statement but then the win are not in the right order. Since I need it to be in order of the eventon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ORDER BY clause that uses two columns will sort by the first column, using the second column only as a tie breaker.  In the clause you posted

```
ORDER BY events.eventon DESC, fighterfighthistories.id ASC
```

the data in the "eventon" column has unique values, so there are no ties to break.

This is your data.

```
   seq win eventon
1   1   1   31-12-2000
2   9   1   30-12-2000
3   1   1   21-12-2000
4   2   1   11-12-2000
5   1   0   10-12-2000
6   1   0   01-12-2000
```

It is correctly sorted descending on the column "eventon".